# AIDL parcel usage

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I've read Android Developer sites about Parcels and AIDL but I still have a question.  Why can a Parcelable object be returned from an AIDL interface method but not passed as a parameter into an AIDL method?  I know that AIDL interface methods want primitive data types (as stated by the android developer website) but I am able to pass a Uri object in as a parameter - so why can I not pass a Parcelable object in?

Comment: Your last three sentences (not counting "Thanks") all refer to "this", and it is unclear what you think "this" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parcelable objects using AIDL. The docs say "If you have a class that you would like to send from one process to another through an IPC interface, you can do that. However, you must ensure that the code for your class is available to the other side of the IPC channel and your class must support the Parcelable interface."

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html#PassingObjects

Comment: Yes I did read this.  However when I try to use the Parcelable object as a parameter the AIDL file throws and error.  On the flip side I have no trouble using it as a return type for the interface functions.  From what I've read elsewhere it cannot be used as an in parameter.

Comment: For right now I have moved forward without using them but may come back to this at a later time.  Thus I do not have the code anymore but will for sure post the error I get when I do come back to this.

Comment: @satur9nine can we declare a method like below in .aidl
void sendMessageParcelable(String app, Parcelable parcel)

Comment: @umesh I don't believe it using Parcelable itself will work since Android expects the parameter type to not only implement Parcelable but also to have a CREATOR. See the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html. It also seems to defeat the purpose of using AIDL if you are sending Parcelable itself since it has no specific meaning. You might consider using ContentProvider#call instead if you want a flexible IPC solution that is synchronous.